# React-Navigation StackNavigator header not showing

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to get the StackNavigator to work from react-navigation.org

I have another app that I'm successfully using TabNavigator which shows up fine.

Things I've tried so far to try and get this to work..

- Copied the code literally line by line, no change
- Checked each package version with yarn, no change
- Moved the AppRegistry, no change

Not sure what to try next...

index.ios.js

```
import App from './src/App'
```

/src/App.js

```
/* @flow */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native'
import QuestionList from './questionRow/QuestionList'
import React from 'react'
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Questions',
    }

    state = {}

    render() {
        return <QuestionList />
    }
}

const AIBUApp = StackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: App},
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('aibu', () => App)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't doing the correct App Registry.

Should have been...

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('aibu', () => AIBUApp)
```

Doesn't matter where you place this, can either be in the App.js or the index.ios/android.js